# Mapping nested dictionary and upate it in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have nested dictionary and want to sum it most nested dictionary like this:

```
{
"USA":{
    '008612':{
        'January':{
            'target':345,
            'achieved':0
        },
        'Febuary':{
            'target':305,
            'achieved':0
        },
        'March':{
            'target':345,
            'achieved':0
        },
    },
    '001232':{
        'January':{
            'target':245,
            'achieved':0
        },
        'Febuary':{
            'target':205,
            'achieved':0
        },
        'March':{
            'target':105,
            'achieved':0
        },
    }
    
},
"UK":{
    '008612':{
        'January':{
            'target':645,
            'achieved':0
        },
        'Febuary':{
            'target':505,
            'achieved':0
        },
        'March':{
            'target':445,
            'achieved':0
        },
    },
    '001232':{
        'January':{
            'target':745,
            'achieved':0
        },
        'Febuary':{
            'target':605,
            'achieved':0
        },
        'March':{
            'target':405,
            'achieved':0
        },
    }
    
}
```

}

Required this type of dictionary that Total dictionary contains the sum of target and achieved of same item code{008612} and same month. For example, the same item code with the same month should be added to the Total dictionary that is newly added:

```
{
 "Total":{
    '008612':{
        'January':{
            'target':990=345+645,
            'achieved':0=0+0
        },
        'Febuary':{
            'target':810,
            'achieved':0
        },
        'March':{
            'target':790,
            'achieved':0
        },
    },
    '001232':{
        'January':{
            'target':890,
            'achieved':0
        },
        'Febuary':{
            'target':810,
            'achieved':0
        },
        'March':{
            'target':510,
            'achieved':0
        },
    },
"USA":{
    '008612':{
        'January':{
            'target':345,
            'achieved':0
        },
        'Febuary':{
            'target':305,
            'achieved':0
        },
        'March':{
            'target':345,
            'achieved':0
        },
    },
    '001232':{
        'January':{
            'target':245,
            'achieved':0
        },
        'Febuary':{
            'target':205,
            'achieved':0
        },
        'March':{
            'target':105,
            'achieved':0
        },
    }
    
},
"UK":{
    '008612':{
        'January':{
            'target':645,
            'achieved':0
        },
        'Febuary':{
            'target':505,
            'achieved':0
        },
        'March':{
            'target':445,
            'achieved':0
        },
    },
    '001232':{
        'January':{
            'target':745,
            'achieved':0
        },
        'Febuary':{
            'target':605,
            'achieved':0
        },
        'March':{
            'target':405,
            'achieved':0
        },
      }
    
 }
```

}

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to  loop through the dictionary and its values multiple times, and compute a separate dictionary to store the calculated values.
Have written a sample code for your reference:

```
total = {}
for k, v in data.items():  # data is the original data dict
    for ik, iv in v.items():
        temp = total.get(ik, {})
        if not temp:
            total[ik] = iv
        else:
            for tk, tv in temp.items():
                for itk, itv in tv.items():
                    temp[tk][itk] += iv[tk][itk]
```

Once the above **total** dictionary is computed, you can then add it to the original data.
Hope this answers your question. Cheers!